# OAuth 2.0 using Google Client for JavaScript, getting permission denied

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-bigquery

Hokay, here's the deal. I'm trying to show very basic functionality of combining BigQuery and Maps API. So, obviously I need OAuth 2.0.
Using Google API Client Library for JavaScript (aka "gapi"), I'm using the following code.

```
var project_id = '***';
var client_id = '***';
var config = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
    'immediate': true
};
function auth() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('***');
    gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
        gapi.client.load("bigquery", "v2");
    });
}
```

This works fine and all, until I try to use a different Gmail account then the one I opened the BigQuery project with. **I get a "permission denied" error.**
The page is hosted online, the credentials have been set so that Redirect URIs is empty, and the JavaScript origins is set to the 2 websites I want people to have access from.

What am I missing? I just want everyone with a gmail account to be able to use my script, from those 2 websites I've given access to :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission denied error is likely because the Google account you are testing with isn't a member of your BigQuery project (with role: READER).

There are two levels of authorization in play here:
(1) Dataset. Eg: is the current user allowed to read/update tables within this dataset?
(2) Project. Eg: who's free/billed quota will be consumed by the query job?

The first one is easy to address -- you can make a dataset public by assigning the special group "authenticated users" via the "share dataset" menu.

The second is more tricky -- you cannot add the world to your project with a reader role.

So, you can't (directly) expose query access to the web.

You have a few alternative options:

(1) If you only want to share this site with a small number of users, you could add them to your project individually.

(2) You could require users to provide their own BigQuery project for billing purposes.

Neither of those provide the seamless experience you probably want, so you could consider a more involved option:

(3) You could set up a front-end service that authenticates as your account (or better -- a service account[1]). Google AppEngine makes this pretty easy, but you can do it with most hosting environments.

--

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts

Comment: Yep, #3 is the correct way to develop an application like this. You can't securely do this in pure JS; you'd want to have an app backend (which can be hosted anywhere) that does your BiqQuery stuff and authorizes with a service account.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/authorization#service-accounts-server