# What's the cleanest approach to hitting the BigQuery API from the browser?

Tags: browser, google-bigquery

I've Googled around and can't see a clear winner. I've looked into using [google-auth-library-nodejs](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs) via Browserify, but unfortunately, it depends on environment variables which won't be around on the browser. What's another way to use Application Default Credentials or a similar low-friction auth approach so I can make REST calls to BigQuery from a browser app?

Comment: Can you describe your problem in more detail? You mention a browser app -- will you have arbitrary (perhaps unauthenticated) users? One of my previous replies might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347800/oauth-2-0-using-google-client-for-javascript-getting-permission-denied/28372486#28372486

Comment: This is for an internal app at our company, so I do want arbitrary users (everyone in the company has access to these BigQuery projects) to be able to use this web app without logging in. Is there no way to do this without writing a proxy server that handles the auth?

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, you have two options:

(1) Create your own frontend, which could even be done with AppsScript[1] for a small organization. Create a service account for your project and submit all of the operations as that account.

(2) Add all of your users as project members and have them log in to the site. Their queries will run as their user, but be billed to your project.

I would strongly recommend option #1, as it allows you to control which queries are being executed and perform caching as appropriate. You can certainly use BigQuery to build dashboard solutions, but you probably don't want every page load to hit the BigQuery API (for both latency and cost reasons).

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/